# Multi touch events

Tags: android, image, events

There is an image in my activity, on touch listener of particular coordinates I am changing the image so that the image from the drawable folder will get loaded on the current image. Now I want a loop for multiple touch so that when the touch event is occurred again, the image will get changed. Should I apply a for loop for touch listener? How? Please help. Here is the code.

```
final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            int ax1=324;
                int ay1=522;

                int ax2=394;
                int ay2=575;

            int ax =  (int) event.getX();
                int ay = (int) event.getY();

                if(ax>=ax1 && ax<=ax2 && ay>=ay1 && ay<=ay2){

                     touchView.setOnTouchListener(this);
                     img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.num2);

                }

            }
return true;
        }
    });
```

Here, the imageView1 is the main image and img1 is a part of image which resides on the main image. Now on the first touch, the image "num2" will get loaded on img1 and on the next touch "num3" will get loaded.

Comment: No need of `for` loop. maintain one `int` variable, and increment its value for every `ACTION_DOWN` event and get the appropriate image based on this value from drawable folder like if `int` value is `1` , then load `R.drawable.num1`, if value is `2`, then load `R.drawable.num2`... A better approach is concatinating the value of `int` to a String `num` like `String s = "num"+value` and load drawable based on this String value...

Answer (score 0):

// get pointer index from the event object
    int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();

```
// get pointer ID
int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
```

Based on multi touch you can decide your selection. [multi touch](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html)